# Text not split correctly using "." delimiter

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a text which consists of a set of sentences.
I am trying to split this text into individual sentences like this:

```
val sentences: Array[String] = text.split(".")
```

However, when I check the `sentences` array (like in the line below), I observe that the array is empty:

```
println("Sentences are: " + sentences.mkString(" "))
```

Why is the splitting not done correctly?

For the text:

```
A sword is a bladed weapon intended for both cutting and thrusting. The precise definition of the term varies with the historical epoch or the geographical region under consideration. A sword in the most narrow sense consists of a straight blade with two edges.
```

The output is:

```
Sentences are:
```

Comment: Do you have a min example in hand? I am a beginner in Scala but I want to help.

Comment: I was talking about code too. :)

Comment: The code containing it is a bit more complex, I don't think it would help.

Comment: Yes I can imagine. The idea of the min example is that you provide a minimal example of code that reproduces the behavior you are facing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String.split expects a regular expression, and `.` means "anything" in regular expressions, so you need to escape it:

```
val sentences: Array[String] = text.split("\\.")
```

Now, if your delimiter is a single character, you can use the overloaded `split(char)` method that will not interpret the argument as regex.

```
val sentences: Array[String] = text.split('.')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.String#split(String)` method splits by RegEx rather than character sequence. `.` is a special regex character that matches *any*  character (including letters). Thus, you end up splitting by *everything*, which yields an empty array. You can avoid this by escaping the `.` character in the regex:

```
val sentences: Array[String] = text.split("\\.")
                                        // ^ escape using \
```

Comment: Why does it need a double \ in this case? For instance the code `replaceAll("\"", "")` works as well, although it has only one.

Comment: This is an inconsistency in the Strings library. Some methods take a string literal as the pattern others take a regex expressed as a string. Best way is to look at the ScalaDocs or experiment on the REPL each time you do something like this.

Comment: @octavian you are passing the string `\.`, but to express a string literal with that content in Scala, you need to [escape the escape backslash](https://xkcd.com/1638/), so it becomes `\\`.

Comment: You can also use raw string interpolation: `raw"\."` to avoid having to escape the escape.